# androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat is deprecated

Tags: java, android, androidx

What should be used because that class is deprecated. ***ParcelableCompat*** is deprecated, ***newCreator()*** is deprecated, ***ParcelableComparCreatorCallbacks<>*** is deprecated. Thanks!

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
            = ParcelableCompat.newCreator(new ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<SavedState>() {

        @Override
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
            return new SavedState(in, loader);
        }

        @Override
        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }

    });
```

Comment: You should always refer to API documentation on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompat) for API changes. Certainly you will get your answer from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompat) documentation

> **ParcelableCompat class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.**
>
> Use [Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator.html) directly.

So change your code from

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
        = ParcelableCompat.newCreator(new ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<SavedState>() {

    @Override
    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
        return new SavedState(in, loader);
    }

    @Override
    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SavedState[size];
    }

});
```

to

```
public static final Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState> CREATOR 
        = new Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState>() {

    @Override
    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return createFromParcel(source, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
        return new SavedState(source, loader);
    }
    
    @Override
    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SavedState[size];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Android dev Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompat) ask you to use [Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator.html) directly from API v26.1.0 onward.

```
public static interface Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator implements Creator<T> 

android.os.Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<T>
```